# Without axiom of choice, how big can the product of a family be?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

With AC, we have the König's theorem which says that for two family of cardinals
$\kappa_i$ and $\lambda_i$, if for all $i$, $\kappa_i < \lambda_i$, then
$\sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i < \prod_{i\in I} \lambda_i$.

Without AC, $\prod_{i\in I} \lambda_i$ could be empty. But can its cardinality be anything between $0$ and $\sum_{i\in I} \kappa_i$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This requires some additional clarification.

In principle, when we talk about sums and products of cardinals, we want to say that these do not depend on the choice of the sets we put into the sum and products. But without the axiom of choice it is quite possible that the infinite sums and products of cardinals are not well-defined to begin with.

We can overcome this by saying that ultimately König's theorem is about ordinals, so we are talking about the sum and products of these specific ordinals, and then the cardinalities of those sums and products.

As such, the sums are always well-orderable, at least assuming that the index set was well-orderable. The products, on the other hand, need not be well-orderable. For example, if $\Bbb R$ cannot be well-ordered, then the only infinite products of ordinals which can be well-ordered are those where $0$ appears, or where co-finitely many of the ordinals are $1$.

Still, we can easily show that if the $\prod\lambda_i$ *can* be well-ordered, then it is certainly strictly larger than the sum $\sum\kappa_i$, under the assumption that $\kappa_i<\lambda_i$, of course. The reason is simple: the well-order gives you all the choice you needed for the proof of König's theorem.

---

Note that if you simply require that $\kappa_i$ are *ordinals* and that $\kappa_i<\lambda_i$, we can get an odd situation, with $\lambda_i=\kappa_i+1$, $I=\omega$, and $\sum\kappa_i=\aleph_1$, $\prod\lambda_i=2^{\aleph_0}$, but the two cardinals are incomparable in that case!

Of course in this case neither $\kappa_i$ nor $\lambda_i$ is a cardinal, so this is really stretching the definitions thin.

Comment: I realised that in my textbook, König's theorem is formulated as follows: 
Let $(X_i:i\in I)$ and $(Y_i: i\in I)$ be two families of sets and assume that for every $i\in I$, $card(X_i) <card(Y_i)$, then  
$\sum_{i\in I} X_i < \prod_{i\in I} Y_i$. 

Now $\prod_{i\in I} Y_i$ is always well-defined. Without AC, what can we say about its cardinality?

Comment: In the last example, with ordinal is $\kappa_i$?

Comment: Absolutely nothing.

Comment: It could be that each $X_i$ is a set of size 2, and each $Y_i$ is a set of size three, and yet the sum and product are incomparable.

Comment: If each $Y_i$ is a set of size three, then at least we could say that if the product is not empty, then it has at least the cardinality of $I$ no?

Comment: If each $X_i$ is of size $2$, and $I=w$, is the sum of $X_i$ still $w$?

Comment: Suppose that $P_i$ for $i\in I=\omega$ is a family of pairs such that no infinite subfamily admits a choice function. Consider $Y_i = P_i\cup\{i\}$. Now $\prod Y_i$ is not empty. But all choice functions are cofinitely equal to $f(i)=i$. So if the product has a countably infinite subset we can use it to define a choice function from infinitely many $P_i$s. Therefore, no, the product need not be greater than the index set.

Comment: No, in the my previous example is what I was alluding for. Each $P_i$ has size $2$, and $I$ is $\omega$. But the union is Dedekind-finite, so in particular it contains no countably infinite subset.

Comment: I don't know if I understand correctly. Do you mean that the union of $\omega$ sets of size two is not $\omega$?

Comment: Is not necessarily countable. No. You need to choose for each pair which is the first and which is the second. That requires choice.

Comment: When you say that $\sum \kappa_i=\aleph_1$, what are $\kappa_i$?