# $\lambda_i=\kappa_i+1$, $I=\omega$, and $\sum\kappa_i=\aleph_1$, $\prod\lambda_i=2^{\aleph_0}$

Tags: logic, set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

The following is part of the answer of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4185280/without-axiom-of-choice-how-big-can-the-product-of-a-family-be/4185294?noredirect=1#comment8677401_4185294),

> Note that if you simply require that $\kappa_i$ are *ordinals* and that $\kappa_i<\lambda_i$, we can get an odd situation, with $\lambda_i=\kappa_i+1$, $I=\omega$, and $\sum\kappa_i=\aleph_1$, $\prod\lambda_i=2^{\aleph_0}$, but the two cardinals are incomparable in that case!

I cannot think of what $\kappa_i$ should be for these equalities to hold. I this is worth a separate question.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a consistency result. It is not an actual example, since under the axiom of choice the countable sum of countable ordinals is countable and not $\aleph_1$. But your question *was* about the failure of König's theorem without choice.

In short, if we take a singular cardinal $\lambda$, we can make it into $\aleph_1$ of a universe of $\sf ZF$, in which case its cofinality will be countable. That means that there will be some sequence like that, although it is not necessary that this sequence is somehow "easy to define".